# Postgresql performance issue on DigitalOcean VPS

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I have two instances of Postgresql. One is local (Macbook Pro Retina 15), another is on Digital Ocean $10 instance. Config is almost identical (mostly basic). The same db dump loaded on both. The issue is that execution time of the simple select query against 50k items table is almost 5x higher on remote instance.

Local:

```
explain (analyze,buffers) select * from car_trims limit 100 offset 40000;
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=842.14..844.24 rows=100 width=66) (actual time=11.193..11.212 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=450
   ->  Seq Scan on car_trims  (cost=0.00..1139.01 rows=54101 width=66) (actual time=0.006..6.832 rows=40100 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=450
 Planning time: 0.053 ms
 Execution time: 11.236 ms
(6 rows)
```

Remote:

```
explain (analyze,buffers) select * from car_trims limit 100 offset 40000;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=830.91..832.99 rows=100 width=66) (actual time=46.167..46.321 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=439
   ->  Seq Scan on car_trims  (cost=0.00..1124.18 rows=54118 width=66) (actual time=0.060..26.080 rows=40100 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=439
 Planning time: 0.206 ms
 Execution time: 46.442 ms
(6 rows)
```

Is that how it's supposed to be due to more powerful hardware? Or there's a room for tuning? What tools could I use to localize the issue?

UPD: I did some warm-up before executing these queries. Also just in case I performed vacuum and reindexed this table.

Comment: Did you run the same query twice to warm the buffer cache?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. And the results are deviating significantly on the remote, but they are mostly around 40ms. On local server exec time is more stable, drift is about 2-3ms.

Comment: I have a guess, but I'm not sure about postgresql internals. I have 4 cores on the mac and the DO instance is a single core. So if postgresql could use 4 cores within one request, that would be meaningful explanation. Is that the case?

Comment: The times are just too low. (40 ms is nothing) BTW: the planning time is a factor 4 lager too on the remote machine. Maybe it is loaded with concurrent accesses?

Comment: Yeah, thought about it too and shut down app server for a test. Nothing changed. Yeah, 40ms is nothing, but it's just 50k of records in the table. Originally it was an attempt to fix pl-procedure which was planned to improve the performance (and it was so on dev), but on production it turned out to be 600ms and it was using that 50k rows table joined.

Comment: PostgreSQL will only use one core for any given query, so that's not really relevant.

Comment: I would bet this is caused only by hardware differences: CPU architecture, Memory size and so on... By the way (not related to the question): I have a DO server too and I got very significant performance increase setting `random_page_cost=1`, because HD is pretty fast (SDD) and my database fits +/-50% in RAM.